AWS LAmbda - Send SQS Message in foreach is loop not consistent
I am breaking my head over this for two days now. I have a Lambda function with two foreach loops, in which SQS messages are send. The one is working the other not.
The working function:
const restoreCustomers = async (): Promise<void> => {
  try {
    await Promise.all([
      customers.map(async (customer) => {
        const params: SendMessageCommandInput = {
          QueueUrl: customerSqsUrl,
          MessageBody: JSON.stringify(customer),
          MessageGroupId: 'CUSTOMER',
          MessageDeduplicationId: customer.id,
        }

        const command = new SendMessageCommand(params)
        await sqsClient.send(command)

        return true
      }),
    ])
  } catch (error) {
    throw error
  }
}

And this one is not:
const restoreProducts = async (): Promise<void> => {
  try {
    await Promise.all([
      products.map(async (product) => {
        const params: SendMessageCommandInput = {
          QueueUrl: productSqsUrl,
          MessageBody: JSON.stringify(product),
          MessageGroupId: 'PRODUCT',
          MessageDeduplicationId: product.barcode,
        }

        const command = new SendMessageCommand(params)
        await sqsClient.send(command)

        return true
      }),
    ])
  } catch (error) {
    throw error
  }
}

What am I missing, I cant figure out what is different.
I added logging before and after sqsQlient.send() and the loop is logging all 'before' logs, but none of the 'after' logs.
I also tried a for loop and strangely enough this runs fine:
const restoreProducts = async (): Promise<void> => {
  try {
    for (let idx = 0; idx < 144; idx++) {
        const params: SendMessageCommandInput = {
          QueueUrl: productSqsUrl,
          MessageBody: JSON.stringify(products[idx]),
          MessageGroupId: 'PRODUCT',
          MessageDeduplicationId: products[idx].barcode,
        }

        const command = new SendMessageCommand(params)
        await sqsClient.send(command)
    }
  } catch (error) {
    throw error
  }
}


I'm not a node person, but I know that there are potential problems running async where the Lambda function exits before a command has completed running. This might assist: How to wait for async actions inside AWS Lambda?

Can you define working? I think the previous comment might be on to something read over this... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function

@john-rotenstein Thanks I wil read that, but I have a ton of Lambda's with async/await, al working flawlessly. And the restoreCustomers is working fine. All customers are ending up in the queue.

@jackie With working fine, I mean all messages end up in the SQS queue.

I even split them up in different Lambda's with only the restore... function, but the restoreProducts is the only one I cannot get to work.

Can you make it do the same thing if you mock out sqs? Or at least make a minimum example?

@jackie Not sure what you mean by "mock out", It must have something to do with the sqs-send command, als de console.log before this command is written every instance of the loop, but the console.log after the command never. But then it wouldn't  make sense why it works in a simple 'for' loop. I did try it with just a few 'products' (3) but still the same problem.

Mocking would help you prove what is going wrong. If it is the send command the mock will work but the send command still will not.
